# read certain row from CSV file using values from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset (15gb) in a csv file. however, I am only interested in a small number of row from this dataset. I don't want to read/import the whole dataset as it would take forever. I only want the observations whose values in some columns match values in a dataframe in R.
For example sake, the CSV dataset contains information of US citizens. and the dataframe in R contains people in my hometown. How do I read-in/import only the information of people in my hometown from the CSV dataset?
thanks guys

Comment: Please show some more specific code or attempted implementation.

Comment: sorry I don't know, thats why I asked.